# VB6, How to limit user access to html files inside a folder

Tags: html, vb6

**Hi everybody**

i want to display some HTML file  in a visual basic 6 application and i use the browser object.
 is there anyway to prevent these files to be viewed by other browsers? in other words, i want only my application can access the HTML file's contents. could you bring me an example about your solution if you have one?

**Note:** the html files are inside user computer (offline). and i don't want to use .net

Thank u

Comment: I'm not familiar with the VB6 browser control, but would it allow to load an html string from an embedded resource? Another way would be to en- and decrypt the html files in your application before passing them to the browser control.

Comment: Than you Fliburt for your response. another way is to en-decrypt the folder that html files are inside. but i don't now how

Comment: Out of curiosity why are you using VB6 for this?

Comment: Do you need to write to those html files, create new ones or delete from your application?

Comment: Spencer: because most of my users are using windows XP 2000 and don't want to install .netframework

Comment: Filburt: no i dont want to take any actions about the files

Comment: @DavidPeterson: Note that .NET isn't actually anything to do with the internet, online or offline.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The WebBrowser control (part of IE, not VB6) will accept navigation using the `res:` protocol.  This means you can embed HTML resources in your program or create separate HTML resource DLLs.

Use "HTML" as the resource *type* and the "file name" of each item as the resource *id*.

Then access is fairly simple:

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate "res://" & App.Path _
                   & "\" & App.EXEName _
                   & ".exe/HTML/sample.htm"
```

Images and other linked items can use relative URLs:

```
<body background="image.jpg">
```

... where `image.jpg` is another HTML resource containing a JPEG image.

This doesn't provide anything like encryption but it does make casual spelunking and viewing of your HTML less likely.